# Is it ok to pass class component reference to child component in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, pass-by-reference, setstate

```
class Parent extends React.Component {

    handler = (event) => {
        this.setState(state => ({ count: state.count + 1 }));
    }

    render() {
        return (
          <div>
            {this.state.count}
            <Child Parent={this} />
          </div>
        );
    }
}

function Child(props) {
    return <button onClick={props.Parent.handler}>increment count</button>
}
```

I have used this type of pattern a few times, didn't find any consequence, does anyone see any harm following such a pattern?

Comment: no, it's wrong pattern. You need to send only property which you wanna use inside child component.

Comment: what do you think, would make it a wrong pattern?

Comment: you child component will be re-render every time when something changed on parent component. In your case it make no sense (benefits) to have child component at all!

Comment: that is always true unless we memoize child, child will re-render for every render of parent

Comment: regarding your point of sending only required properties, sometimes there are so many properties to be sent, that one ponders,what if I could send the class instance directly and that is the purpose of the question

Comment: Because `this` has all prototype and class functions and properties, which you will not use anyway.

Comment: honestly, as I understand, it doesn't hurt, even if, this has ton's of other properties, because we pass `this` by reference

Answer (score 0):

> sometimes there are so many properties to be sent

In my opinion, if `Child` use almost all properties in `Parent`, maybe:

1. `Child` is `Parent` ?
2. split `Child` to multi Child like `Child1`、`Child2` ?

And, if you pass `Parent` to `Child`, it's not semantic. I cannot aware what properties that `Child` needed when I use it elsewhere.

Looking forward to more discussion. :)

Comment: your comment is ok, but it still doesn't touch the essence of the question, your 3 arguments don't appeal

Comment: @AkshayVijayJain okay, maybe you have your own special scenes. But I still insist that it is necessary to expose only the required interfaces. If unnecessary interfaces are exposed, there will be uncontrollable risks, which is very dangerous in my opinion. After all, you can't guarantee how others use them.

Comment: this argument seems a bit valid, but the child is actually a child of Parent, that child does not have existence without parent, I mean to say, Parent can remove that child component, if it does something extra and implement new child that does the required work

Answer (score 0):

I am adding some benefits we get with this pattern, and I assume with my limited knowledge that this is ok

1. we can access props and state of Parent directly in child
2. can change parent state from child, using `Parent.setState`
3. can access other functions defined on the Parent class and thus reduce passing down everything as props

I feel this is a much better solution, because Parent reference never changes and therefore, it does not cause unnecessary rerender of child, and we do not need to memorize Parent' function references that we pass to child

While an argument of code smell may be raised by OO Specialist, that we are allowing child to modify properties of parent, we can safely ignore it for React, since we are anyway passing whole redux store to every component and any change in redux store, impacts so many components simultaneously.
---- following is an except from same question i posted on freecodeCamp. ------
Regarding code smell, only because one class is modifying other class’s properties. We have to think twice.

the whole concept of state is there so that it can be modified internally,

whether a class itself modifies or it gives right to some child to modify – it’s kind of similar thing, it’s only delegation that is the addition

Always to note, that the parent has full control over child. if child is not acting as per parent, the child can be replaced by parent.

To add one more point, we are anyways giving every component the right to modify whole redux store by useDispatch, thus argument of code smell doesn’t hold so strong for React per se

https://forum.freecodecamp.org/t/is-it-ok-to-pass-class-component-reference-to-child-component-in-react/408341/7